# How to Define the Display Matrix from two linear mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm working right now on this task, but i dont't know how to start, 
Im glad for every hint, I hope we can solve this task together 
$$  Given \,  are \,  the \,  following \,  ordered \,  Bases \,  of \, \mathbb{R²}, \mathbb{R³} \,  and \,  \mathbb{R⁴}$$ 
$$
B₂= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
B₃= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
B₄= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
$$ Let \, us \, consider \, now \, two \, linear \, mappings \, \varphi:\mathbb{R²} →  \mathbb{R³} \, \, \psi:  \mathbb{R³} \, →   \,  \mathbb{R⁴} $$
$$
\varphi
\begin{pmatrix} 
v1 \\
v2 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
v1 - v2 \\
0 \\
2v1 - v2 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
and \, \psi
\begin{pmatrix} 
v1\\
v2 \\
v3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
v₁ + 2v₃ \\
v₂ - v₃ \\
v₁ + v₂ \\
2v₁ + 3v₃  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
$$ Define \, the \, display \, matrix \, M 
\begin{matrix} 
B₂  \\
B₃  
\end{matrix}
   (\varphi), \, M 
\begin{matrix} 
B₃  \\
B₄  
\end{matrix}
(\psi) \, and \, M 
\begin{matrix} 
B₂  \\
B₄  
\end{matrix}
(\psi \, ○  \, \varphi)
$$

Thank you for any hint :)
[Definition of the display matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNusQ.jpg)

Comment: Do you know the definition of a display matrix?

Comment: Yes sure, I added it as a picture in the main question.

Comment: Then just apply it. Put each basis vector into the function and write the corresponding image as a linear combination of the other basis. The coefficients of that linear combination are then the entries of the matrix, just as the definition states.